# MS Visio (.vsd) Binary File Format Structure Documentation

Tags: c#, c++, ms-office, visio, ole

Would anybody have Microsoft Visio 2003 - 2010 (.vsd) binary file structure documentation?

I am talking about the older OLE2 compound binary file format (Visio 2003 - 2010) (ex., .vsd, .vsw), not the newer Open XML file format, like .vsdx, .vstx, ...

I spent a lot of time on internet (especially Microsoft Website) trying to find it. Unfortunately, so far without success. Thank you.

Comment: I don't think there is any documentation available. There is a [library for it](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/DLP/Libraries/libvisio) presumably done by reverse engineering. And [utilities to poke around in the format](https://github.com/renyxa/re-lab/tree/master/oletoy) that were used in the RE effort.

Comment: Unlike the `.vsd` format, `.vsdx` format is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/visio/visio-file-format-reference).

Comment: Hi rustyx, yes, I konw that. However, the point is that I need the older one, .vsd.

Comment: BTW, do you have some practical problem to solve, or you are asking out of a curiosity?

Comment: The binary format was done in time where computers were much less powerful and hard drive were quite small so these format are quite condensed and surely very hard to understand. Have you considered using a library for that. A Google search gave me : https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPVisio.

Comment: Hi @Nikolay, indeed, I am programming a tool, which must support compound binary Visio data formats (.vsd, vst, vsw,...). I have to extract and analyze VBA Macro content, therefore understanding file structure is quite important here.

Comment: @Phil1970, I work on C# Blazor project. I will check libraries, but since I already managed other binary formats from MS Office package (Excel, Word, PowerPoint, Publisher, MS Project), I would prefer having clean solution without a library for one data format. However, I could possibly reverse engineer a library for Python or PHP.

Comment: I see. I would try going with some library and reverse engineer. The most capable commercial one that can read binary Visio files is aspose. Not sure if it can also parse binary VBA projects though, but you probably already have some solution for this sub-task.

Comment: P.S. I admire your bravery. If I were given such a project, I would immediately give up (:

Comment: @Nikolay, thank you mate :-) Well, I was solving step after step. I solved 26 file extensions (both binary OLE and Open XML), and now I am left with the last 7 Visio binary extensions to solve. Thank you for your support ans answers. I gathered few new ideas. I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your findings are correct, binary vsd format is not publicly documented.

Comment: would you know, pls., where to read official statement, that VIsio compound binary file-structure is not publicly available? Thanks.

Comment: I don't have a direct link to Microsoft stating that. But VSD is a proprietary file format (this can be ensured using Wikipedia article with appropriate references). Then, official docs for other office binary formats can be found in one place, and Visio is not there: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_file_formats/ms-offfflp/6ae2fd93-51fc-4e75-a54a-1b175c627b51